# Progress bar while form is loading

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have created a lot of UserControls which have heavy background images. I placed them on a form. Everything works nice after form's loading has finished.
Problem is - it takes 10 seconds before form appears on screen.

I searched through the internet and found a solution - showing a temporary form saying "Please wait...".

Now I am wondering is there a possibility to replace "Please wait" message with `ProgressBar`. Not marquee one. The one which would actually show form's loading progress.

I examined code and it turned out that heavy part is located in `InitializeComponent`. `InitializeComponent` is generated automatically so I should not edit manually, right? 
I tried to move `InitializeComponent` to separate thread. It turned out to be a bad idea because controls should not be created in different threads.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - what have you tried doing to achieve it?

Comment: To do this you need to know how to create a multithreaded application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a Progress bar on Form Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164707/using-a-progress-bar-on-form-load)

Comment: @UnholySheep: I edited my question trying to explain my problem more clearly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen: Please give me some advice. Is it posible to create controls in background thread and then place them on form?

Comment: @Walruz You place a progessbar in your form. Then you run your code on a seperate thread and push progressbar updates from that thread to your main thread (where the gui runs on). You should check Furkan Ayik's answer.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen: I get cross-thread exception when I move InitializeComponent to BackgroundWorker

Comment: Can you maybe post your code?

Comment: Multiple ways to do so, background worker if you actually need to load stuff or just make a seperate form and show it inside initialize component for a delayed number of seconds, you can also use a timer to update it.
basically spoofing a splash screen.

Comment: This is what progressbar works. Try to search useful articles and some solution on Github or Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out background worker.

[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

[BackgroundWorker Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

https://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

there are methods u can use for progress bar. I think it might help. Good luck.

Comment: Is it posible to create controls in background thread and then place them on form?

Comment: I don't get it what do you mean placing on form but i used it before. When u use background worker, it works distanced from form, in background. Your do_work function makes it. And u can use **progressChanged** event for handle progress bar. Check out 3. link that i give. Also you can find a lot of example. Search for it. And let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already experienced you cannot run the `InitializeComponent` method in another thread. But you can delay some initialization. If you are sure that the image loading is so slow (are they downloaded from a remote location?), then remove the image initialization from the designer (eg. by nullifying the `Image` properties) and load them only after the form is shown:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    await LoadImages();
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}

// Just represents a simple source-target mapping so you can associate the loaded images with their targets
// Here I use a path-control mapping just for the case of the example
private ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, Control>> GetImageMapping()
{
    var basePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures), "Sample Pictures");
    var mapping = new Dictionary<string, Control>
    {
        [Path.Combine(basePath, "Tulips.jpg")] = this, // form1
        [Path.Combine(basePath, "Chrysanthemum.jpg")] = button1,
        // etc, eg. myUserControl1...
    };

    return mapping;
}

private async Task LoadImages()
{
    var mapping = GetImageMapping();
    progressBar1.Maximum = mapping.Count;
    foreach (var item in mapping)
    {
        var image = await LoadImage(item.Key);
        item.Value.BackgroundImage = image;
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}

private async Task<Image> LoadImage(string imagePath)
{
    // This makes 1s delay for each image to imitate slow loading. You do NOT need this line actually.
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    // Only this part will be executed in another thread:
    return await Task.Run<Image>(() =>
    {
        // or download it, load from a stream, resource, whatever...
        var result = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        return result;
    });
}
```

Please note that the form can be closed before the loading progress finishes so you might need some extra checks, too.